# knockoutjs extender observable unknown via with binding

Tags: knockout.js

Hello I have a KnockoutJs computed observable ItemCountText in an extender "paged" that extends an observableArray. The observableArray is Products.

This works as expected, giving me "32 Products" (32, 48, whatever the number is, plus "Products" or whatever text I passed into the extender's settings)

```
<span data-bind="text:Products.ItemCountText"></span>
```

.. But this

```
<!-- ko with: Products -->
<span data-bind="text:ItemCountText"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

... is broken with *Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: ItemCountText is not defined; Bindings value: text: ItemCountText*

What might be the problem here that causes the extender's computed observable ItemCountText not to be defined within "with: Products" although a "Products.ItemCountText" binding is defined?   It feels as though the binding mechanism for 'ko with:' cannot find its way 'into' the extender.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue. To avoid distractions, the paged extender has everything snipped out that is not relevant to the issue.

**http://jsfiddle.net/J4Nd2/1/**

To experience the issue described above, uncomment HTML line 14 of the fiddle and Run

Knockout is version 2.2.1

Here is the JsFiddle's HTML

```
    <div id="bindMe">
    <span data-bind='text: Yay()'></span>
    <div data-bind="text: Products.ItemCountText"></div>
    <div><span data-bind="text: Products().length"></span> on this page</div>
    <!-- ko with: Products -->
        <ul>
            <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
                <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
<span data-bind='text: Boo'></span>
    <!-- ko with: Products -->
<!--    <div data-bind="text: ItemCountText"></div>  -->
        <div><span data-bind="text: length"></span> on this page</div>
        <ul>
            <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
                <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
    <!-- /ko -->   
</div>
```

Here is the JsFiddle's Javascript

```
ko.extenders.paged = function (target, options) {
    // Settings
    var settings = $.extend({
        "itemcounttext": 'Counted Items'
    }, options);

    target.TotalRecords = ko.observable();
    target.ItemCountText =  ko.computed(function () {
        return target.TotalRecords() + " " + settings.itemcounttext;
    });

    return target;
};
/// -- End paging extender -- \\\

var ViewModel = function()  {
    var self = this;
    self.Yay = ko.observable("Hello World... Products.ItemCountText.. it works great");
self.Boo = ko.observable("But if HTML line 14 is uncommented, why does ItemCountText from extender broke using ko with?");
    self.Products = ko.observableArray([]).extend(
    {
        paged:
        {
            "itemcounttext": 'Products in total'
        }
    });
};

var myViewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById("bindMe"));

myViewModel.Products.push('prod a');
myViewModel.Products.push('prod b');
myViewModel.Products.push('prod c');
myViewModel.Products.TotalRecords(5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After failed experimentation with custom binding where I still couldn't access the properties of an extender, I uncovered a rather simple solution of declaring a sort-of pointer to the 'paged' extender

Products and Changes are both observableArrays extended with an extension named 'paged'

```
self.Products.Paged = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.Products['extend']('paged');
});

self.Changes.Paged = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.Changes['extend']('paged');
});
```

Now I can use the containerless 'with' binding to contain my _Pager view that uses properties of my extender named 'paged', and now anything extended by 'paged' can be bound to my _Pager view

```
<!-- ko with: Products.Paged -->
    @Html.Partial("_Pager",Model)
<!-- /ko -->
```

and

```
<!-- ko with: Changes.Paged -->
    @Html.Partial("_Pager",Model)
<!-- /ko -->
```

Now that I have uncovered this, I bet a custom binding could be written to do the pointing such that the pointer need not be added to everything extended.  Instead, a custom binding named "withExtension" might accept the name of the extension, allowing for

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your observable is created and bound to the view before your data was actually in that ItemCountText -

http://jsfiddle.net/J4Nd2/2/

```
<div data-bind="text: $data.ItemCountText"></div>
```

By appending $data. on the front, it tells Knockout that only bind this if it has a value, basically deferring binding until ItemCountText has a value.

**Edit update**

Your with: binding is ignoring the extended properties because you are binding the context to the value of the array, which doesn't include those extended properties.

```
<!-- ko with: Products -->
<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
```

When you are binding with: products it is almost the same as binding with the value of an observable - any other properties of that object that are not part of the observable value are ignored.

If you must bind within the containerless with binding use $parent.Products to get it back in - http://jsfiddle.net/J4Nd2/4/

Comment: Prepending any context marker will hide the issue from displaying as an error in the javascript console, but the binding still does not succeed. Your fiddle also does not show "5 Products in Total" in the bottom half

Comment: Updated.  You are bindign the context to the value of the observableArray, not to the parent object which you are extending

Comment: See the whole thing is that it's a paging extender. What i am trying to do it reuse it and the paging view that binds to it.  So "with: ChangeLog" wont be able to reuse a view having "$parent.Products" in it.  If a "ko with" can't do it, is there any way the extender's properties be accessed ~generically such that the view could be reused on different paged arrays?

Comment: You are binding it on top of an observable array, if you want each of your objects to have that property than set up a parent observable that has a property that is an observableArray and set the property there

Comment: "...set up a parent observable that has a property that is an observableArray and set the property there.."  Thank you that should work, I think, but I still wonder why text:Products.ItemCountText works as a binding but "With: Products, text:ItemCountText" fails.  Both ways should work the same shouldn't they?

Comment: Nope, because ItemCountText is a property of the JavaScript object Products, but when you are using the with: binding you are binding to the value of the observable or observableArray of Products.  So if you console.log Products() you will get the value of Products that you are binding to, if you console.log(Products) you will see the JavaScript object that is being extended